# Did they deliberately release the new Justice Leage film on the same day the Justice League animated show was broadcast?

Tags: production, dc-extended-universe, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, justice-league-tv

While reading [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-your-review-of-the-Justice-League-2017-movie/answer/Anubhav-Balodhi?srid=2MO4) about a *Justice League* review, I realized that the movie release date shares similarities to the famous Justice League animated show:

[image]

And images like these (most probably fan-arts) are circulating everywhere now. Is it really done on purpose or is it just a coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

With DC, nothing is a coincidence.

This film was released on the 25th anniversary of The Death of Superman comic, which was released November 17, 1992, and the 16th anniversary of Justice League (2001) which premiered its first episode November 17, 2001.

So, it appears that WB Studios just consider this date lucky and/ or just want to tribute to two of the greatest pieces in comics and animated genre.

Comment: Or it's just a co-incidence. Unless you can provide actual **evidence** that this is deliberate...this is just an opinion.